# How to install PHP mbstring on CentOS 6.2

Tags: php, linux, centos, mbstring

How do I install mbstring with PHP on CentOS 6.2

I've tried:

```
$ sudo yum install php-mbstring

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.net.cen.ct.gov
 * extras: centos.aol.com
 * updates: mirrors.seas.harvard.edu
Setting up Install Process
No package php-mbstring available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

But no packages were found?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

do the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
```

under the section `updates`, comment out the mirrorlist line (put a `#` in front of the line), then on a new line write:

```
baseurl=http://centos.intergenia.de/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
```

now try:

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

(afterwards you'll probably want to uncomment the mirrorlist and comment out the baseurl)

Comment: @ninjascorner yes, see the answer & comment below about adding EPEL and installing from there.

Comment: No package **php-mbstring** available.

Answer (score 30):

If you have cPanel hosting you can use Easy Apache to do this through shell. These are the steps.

1. Type the Easy Apache PathType the path for Easy Apache

   > root@vps#### [~]# /scripts/easyapache
2. Do not say yes to the "cPanel update available".
3. Continue through the screens with defaults till you get to the "Exhaustive options list".
4. Page down till you see the Mbstring extension listed and select it.
5. Continue through the Steps and Save the Apache PHP build.

Apache and PHP will now rebuild to include the mbstring extension. Wait for the process to finish ~10 to 30 minutes. Once the process is finished you should see the Mbstring extension in the phpinfo now.

For more detailed steps see the article 
[Installing the mbstring extension with Easy Apache](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/general-server-setup/install-mbstring-easy-apache)

Comment: U gave me a good hint. I use webbased-EasyApache. Running it right now. Vote up as a thanks

Answer (score 20):

Please check your `/etc/yum.conf` file, maybe it is exclude `php` packages.

You should remove `php*` from this line so you can download `php-*` packages:

```
exclude= courier* dovecot* exim* filesystem httpd* mod_ssl* mydns* php*
```

It's seems your server having some scripts like cPanel

Comment: Not able to see in loaded modules after installing, can you guys please help me

Answer (score 12):

1. Find out php version - `php -v`
2. Search for php extensions available - `yum search php-`
3. Install using - `yum install ea-php56-php-mbstring.x86_64`
4. Then `httpd -k restart`

> Package name - ea-php-php-mbstring.x86_64

Comment: IMO this is the correct answer. But instead of `php-` you can just do `yum search mbstring` and no restart is necessary! Just tested it, works fine.

Comment: @j_allen_morris What is your php version?

Comment: 5.6  i used the method outlined below by hoogw.  It worked great.

Answer (score 11):

*Make sure you update your linux box first

```
yum update
```

In case someone still has this problem, this is a valid solution:

> centos-release : rpm -q centos-release

**Centos 6.***

```
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm
```

**Centos 5.***

```
wget http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/Fedora/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-5*.rpm
```

Then just do this to **update**:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi upgrade php-mbstring
```

Or this to **install**:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-mbstring
```

Comment: hi andufo , tried your solution but no luck.. im getting "No package php-mbstring available". (tried installing using root)... here is the complete error message http://pastebin.com/rqvS6QGx

Comment: @andufo : it says "Package php-mbstring-5.6.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version Nothing to do" when I am trying to "# yum --enablerepo=remi install php-mbstring" And I have uncommented the mbstring.dll extension in correct php.ini. I am running 
Centos 6.8 PHP 5.6

Comment: What about Centos 7?

Answer (score 4):

yum install php-mbstring (as per http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php)

I think you have to install the EPEL repository http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Comment: thank fot your answer @Tor P, how i add epel repository ? i dont have now

Comment: im little speak english, can you give me any code ? im try that

Comment: im try this "sudo yum install php-mbstring" and i get this response "No package php-mbstring available."

Comment: I see that your updates repo maps to a different mirror than mine (I get updates.intergenia.org), probably it doesn't have the package... I will check if there are any other repos you might try...

Comment: To add EPEL, do 'rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm' then you can simply do 'yum install php-mbstring'

Comment: There are instructions to do this here:
http://www.parktec.com/2013/02/web-server-on-centos-6-3/
http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-5x-or-6x

But neither of those worked for me on the server I'm working on.

Answer (score 2):

None of above works for godaddy server centOS 6, apache 2.4, php 5.6

Instead, you should

Install the mbstring PHP Extension with EasyApache

check if you already have it by, putty or ssh

php -m | grep mbstring

[if nothing, means missing mbstring]

Now you need to goto godaddy your account page,

click manager server,

open whm ----- search for apache,

open "easy apache 4"(my case)

Now you need customize currently installed packages,

by

click "customize" button on top line next to "currently installed package..."

search mbstring,

click on/off toggle next to it.

click next, next, .... privision..done.

Now you should have mbstring

by check again at putty(ssh)

php -m | grep mbstring  [should see mbstring]

or you can find mbstring at phpinfo() page

Comment: I can confirm that this works.  I just used it because i couldn't use Simple HTML DOM 1.5, but now it works perfectly!!!  Thank you so much.  I can only imagine how much longer i would have been searching if you hadn't posted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As `yum install php-mbstring` then `httpd -k restart` didn't do it for me, I think [these options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php) should be compiled, as documented [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php):

> Now, configure and build PHP. This is where you customize PHP with
> various options, like which extensions will be enabled. Run
> ./configure --help for a list of available options. In our example
> we'll do a simple configure with Apache 2 and MySQL support.
>
> If you built Apache from source, as described above, the below example
> will match your path for apxs, but if you installed Apache some other
> way, you'll need to adjust the path to apxs accordingly. Note that
> some distros may rename apxs to apxs2.
>
> ```
> cd ../php-NN
> ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql --enable-mbstring
> make
> make install
> ```
>
> If you decide to change your configure options after installation,
> you'll need to re-run the configure, make, and make install steps. You
> only need to restart apache for the new module to take effect. A
> recompile of Apache is not needed.
>
> Note that unless told otherwise, 'make install' will also install
> PEAR, various PHP tools such as phpize, install the PHP CLI, and more.

Though [this page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/PHP_configuration) says it's optional:

> **--enable-mbstring**
> Allows multibyte character string support. This is optional, as slower custom code will be used if not available.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue before. In my case, I needed to install php-mbstring extension on GoDaddy VPS server. None of above solutions did work for me.

What I've found is to install PHP extensions using WHM (Web Hosting Manager) of GoDaddy. Anyone who use GoDaddy VPS server can access this page with the following address.

> http://{Your_Server_IP_Address}:2087

On this page, you can easily find Easy Apache software that can help you to install/upgrade php components and extensions. You can select currently installed profile and customize and then provision the profile. Everything with Easy Apache is explanatory.

I remember that I did very similar things for HostGator server, but I don't remember how actually I did for profile update.

**Edit:**
When you have got the server which supports Web Hosting Manager, then you can add/update/remove php extensions on WHM. On godaddy servers, it's even recommended to update PHP ini settings on WHM.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo yum install php<version>w-mbstring
```

ex.
    sudo yum install php56w-mbstring

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above help you out, and you have the option, try obtaining one of the rpm files eg:

wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/x86_64/php-mbstring-5.4.45-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm

then using rpm, install it ignoring the depenecies like so:

rpm -i --nodeps php-mbstring-5.4.45-2.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm

Hope that helps out.