# mbstring & php-common Issue Centos 6.4

Tags: php, linux, phpmyadmin, centos

I'm new to server admin and I'm trying to get phpmyadmin to work, which says it needs mbstring to be installed. I run yum install php-mbstring and get this:

```
[terryg@jupint comicswap]$ yum install php-mbstring
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
You need to be root to perform this command.
[terryg@jupint comicswap]$ sudo yum install php-mbstring
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.cogentco.com
 * epel: epel.mirror.constant.com
 * extras: mirror.beyondhosting.net
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.3.3-23.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4 for package: php-mbstring-       5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
       Installed: php-common-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.20-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: How did you install php-common?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278561/how-to-install-php-mbstring-on-centos-6-2?rq=1