# mbstring installation is returning 'Nothing to do'

Tags: php, linux

i want to install mbstring.. 
(i use 64bit centos 5.8 and cpanel on my server)

could someone help me; what should i do, except **easyapache** (im afraid to do something wrong; or delete any extension or php.ini detail)

i tried these; but no-one works for me:

a)
i tried this link...
[How to install PHP mbstring on CentOS 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278561/how-to-install-php-mbstring-on-centos-6-2)
( `sudo nano /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` etc.. )

and also i install EPEL repository, and get confirmation by these lines:

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
```

but.... stil NOT WORKING...

b) i download rpm file from(8th line):
http://www.rpmseek.com/rpm-pl/php-mbstring.html?hl=com&cs=php-mbstring:PR:0:0:0:0:0

and tried to instal 
`via sudo yum install php-mbstring` OR `sudo yum install php-mbstring.html?hl=com&cs=php-mbstring:PR:0:0:0:0:0` etc....

i alwalys get the same answer: **Nothing to do**

if i write:

```
sudo rpm –ivh php-mbstring-5.1.6-39.el5_8.x86_64.rpm
```

i get this error:

```
RPM version 4.4.2.3
Copyright (C) 1998-2002 - Red Hat, Inc.
This program may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU GPL

    Usage: rpm [-aKfgpWHqV] [-aKfgpWHqVcdils] [-aKfgpWHqVcdilsaKfgpWHqV] [-aKfgpWHqVcdilsaKfgpWHqV] [-aKfgpWHqVcdilsaKfgpWHqV] [-aKfgpWHqVcdilsaKfgpWHqVK] [-aKfgpWHqVcdilsaKfgpWHqVK] [-aKfgpWHqVcdilsaKfgpWHqVKi] [-aKfgpWHqVcdilsaKfgpWHqVKiv] [-aKfgpWHqVcdilsaKfgpWHqVKiv] [-aKfgpWHqVcdilsaKfgpWHqVKiv?] [-a|--all] [-f|--file] [-g|--group]
    [-p|--package] [-W|--ftswalk] [--pkgid] [--hdrid] [--fileid]
    [--specfile] [--triggeredby] [--whatrequires] [--whatprovides]
    [--nomanifest] [-c|--configfiles] [-d|--docfiles] [--dump] [-l|--list]
    [--queryformat=QUERYFORMAT] [-s|--state] [--nomd5] [--nofiles]
    [--nodeps] [--noscript] [--comfollow] [--logical] [--nochdir]
    [--nostat] [--physical] [--seedot] [--xdev] [--whiteout]
    [--addsign] [-K|--checksig] [--delsign] [--import] [--resign]
    [--nodigest] [--nosignature] [--initdb] [--rebuilddb] [--aid]
    [--allfiles] [--allmatches] [--badreloc] [-e|--erase <package>+]
    [--excludedocs] [--excludepath=<path>] [--fileconflicts] [--force]
    [-F|--freshen <packagefile>+] [-h|--hash] [--ignorearch] [--ignoreos]
    [--ignoresize] [-i|--install] [--justdb] [--nodeps] [--nomd5]
    [--nocontexts] [--noorder] [--nosuggest] [--noscripts]
    [--notriggers] [--oldpackage] [--percent] [--prefix=<dir>]
    [--relocate=<old>=<new>] [--repackage] [--replacefiles]
    [--replacepkgs] [--test] [-U|--upgrade <packagefile>+] [--quiet]
    [-D|--define 'MACRO EXPR'] [-E|--eval 'EXPR'] [--macros=<FILE:...>]
    [--nodigest] [--nosignature] [--rcfile=<FILE:...>] [-r|--root ROOT]
    [--querytags] [--showrc] [--quiet] [-v|--verbose] [--version]
    [-?|--help] [--usage] [--scripts] [--setperms] [--setugids]
    [--conflicts] [--obsoletes] [--provides] [--requires] [--info]
    [--changelog] [--xml] [--triggers] [--last] [--dupes]
    [--filesbypkg] [--fileclass] [--filecolor] [--filecontext]
    [--fscontext] [--recontext] [--fileprovide] [--filerequire]
    [--redhatprovides] [--redhatrequires] [--buildpolicy=<policy>]
    [--with=<option>] [--without=<option>]
```

if i write `yum localinstall php-mbstring-5.1.6-39.el5_8.x86_64.rpm` :
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining php-mbstring-5.1.6-39.el5_8.x86_64.rpm: php-mbstring-5.1.6-39.el5_8.x86_64
Nothing to do

if i write `rpm -ivh php-mbstring-5.1.6-39.el5_8.x86_64.rpm` :
error: Failed dependencies:
php-common = 5.1.6-39.el5_8 is needed by php-mbstring-5.1.6-39.el5_8.x86_64

Comment: Same here. Google can't help. All the topics are outdate. Someone please