# Laravel 4 : Running Migration on a VM and getting a mbstring / Symfony error

Tags: symfony, nginx, laravel-4, virtual-machine, vagrant

i am running a laravel project on a Puphpet VM set up (CentOS 6.4 Nginx) and all has been well but I created a new migration file and then went to run it 
[code]php artisan migrate[/code]

Then got the following error message:

```
  PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\Console\mb_detect_encoding() in /vagrant/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 721
  {"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to undefined function Symfony\\Component\\Console\\mb_detect_encoding()","file":"\/vagrant\/vendor\/symfony\/console\/Symfony\/Component\/Console\/Application.php","line":721}}[/code]
```

Now looking around etc i see people refer to the mbstring needs to be installed etc but not sure how to go about this on a VM set up, and is this an update issue as i have managed ti run migration for a while on the VM but today nothing other than the error?

i have got access to the php.ini file and uncommented the following via Vim and set them both to pass, but nothing still even after a server restart.

```
 mbstring.http_input = pass
 mbstring.http_output = pass
```

Any advice appreciated.

As said i am using Puphpet/Vagrant using CentOS 6.4 with Nginx, on a MAC OSX 10.7 && 10.8 running PHP5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to install mb_string, something like:

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

Then load the .so in your php configuration

Comment: Thanks you will give this ago and feedback.

Comment: With a little playing i had to first following the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278561/how-to-install-php-mbstring-on-centos-6-2 as got a No package php5-mbstring available.  But then it still failed, so i changed your string to sudo yum install php-mbstring (without the 5) and it seemed to work no need to add the .so file.

Comment: Ok I wasn't sure, I'm editing my answer then. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error today. In my case the problem was that I had a separate php.ini for CLI, where the extension was not enabled.

After adding:

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

to `php_cli.ini` everything worked fine.