# WAMP: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() .... When going to localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: wampserver, mbstring

I have enabled the mbstring extension by removing the ';':
extension=php_mbstring.dll

I am using the correct php.ini file, checked by using phpinfo().

Extension dir specified in php.ini: extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/"
Indeed, when I go there, I find 'php_mbstring.dll'

I've restarted wamp multiple times.

What else can be wrong here?

UPDATE:

seems, my whole wamp installation is fd up with respect to mysql:

Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

I do have mysql installed and everything though...module is also enabled etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you have a rouge php.ini file somewhere and it is loading the wrong one.

There are actually 2 php.ini files in WAMPServer as in most PHP/Apache installations.

One is called `\wamp\bin\php\{phpversion}\php.ini` and this is only used by the PHP CLI

The other is called `\wamp\bin\php\{phpversion}\phpForApache.ini` and is used when you are running PHP through Apache.

If you use the wampmanager menus you will edit the one used by Apache/PHP i.e.

```
wampmanager => PHP -> php.ini
```

However if you have actually edited the correct php.ini then it is likely you have a rouge version of php.ini somewhere on your system.

Run the `phpinfo()` link again from the wampmanager homepage and check this parameter which is shown on the first section of the output.

```
Loaded Configuration File
```

It should be pointing to `\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\phpForApache.ini` in your case.

If its pointing somewhere else then you probably tried to install PHP and Apache manually before finding WAMPServer and that has left a php.ini file somewhere where Apache is finding it.

Here is the [PHP Manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) that defines the search path order used by Apache when looking for a `php.ini` file. This may help you find and remove any rouge versions of `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Install the gd library also.

check this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php

or

There's a much easier way than recompiling PHP. Just yum install the required mbstring library:

Example: [How to install PHP mbstring on CentOS 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278561/how-to-install-php-mbstring-on-centos-6-2)

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-mbstring
```

Oh, and don't forget to restart apache afterward.