# php-mbstring isn't showing in phpinfo();

Tags: php, magento

I'm having some issues with my Magento installation. At the checkout I get the following error:

```
Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding() in public_html/cpanel_user/lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php on line 556
```

From research on Google and SO it seems to be a issue with MB-STRING.
I'm running CentOS with WHM/cPanel on top.

I installed the extension using the following command:

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

Rebooted the httpd via the following command:

```
service httpd restart
```

If you need anymore info let me know, I'm desperately looking to solve this issue.

Comment: just a wild guess, maybe need to enable it in `php.ini`

Comment: I added the following to the php.ini and it didn't make a difference:

extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=mbstring.so

Comment: see if this post help...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278561/how-to-install-php-mbstring-on-centos-6-2, hopefully it works :)

Comment: That didn't help, but I managed to fix the issue with the EasyApache via cPanel..