# LARAVEL INSTALLATION: NO "EXTENSION = PHP_MBSTRING.DLL" in "PHP.INI"

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

I am an absolute beginner of laravel framework and even web development.

PHP version I have is 5.6.
I am having trouble installing laravel framework on my Amazon Linux Server.

Below is the first error I confronted.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/framework v5.2.9 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.8 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.7 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.39 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.38 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.37 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.36 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.35 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.34 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.33 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.32 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.31 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.30 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.29 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.28 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.27 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.26 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.25 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.24 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.23 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.22 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.21 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.20 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.19 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.18 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.17 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.16 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.15 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.14 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.13 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.12 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.11 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.10 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- Installation request for laravel/framework 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.0, v5.2.1, v5.2.10, v5.2.11, v5.2.12, v5.2.13, v5.2.14, v5.2.15, v5.2.16, v5.2.17, v5.2.18, v5.2.19, v5.2.2, v5.2.20, v5.2.21, v5.2.22, v5.2.23, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.29, v5.2.3, v5.2.30, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.33, v5.2.34, v5.2.35, v5.2.36, v5.2.37, v5.2.38, v5.2.39, v5.2.4, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.2.8, v5.2.9].

 To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
- /etc/php.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-bz2.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-curl.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-dom.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-simplexml.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-tokenizer.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-xml.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-xsl.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/20-zip.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/30-wddx.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/30-xmlreader.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/40-json.ini
- /etc/php-5.6.d/php.ini
 You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

After several research, it seems like I had to uncomment the line **"extension = php.mbstring.dll**. So I tried to find it, **but the php.ini file in my AWS server does not even have the line in it.** Then I put the line by myself, but now I have to deal with a different error.

I have no idea what to do anymore. Has anyone ever had any similar problem like this before? If you have, could you help me with this issue?

My English is not my first language, so if this post does not make sense or you need more information, let me know as well!

Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would need to let us know which OS the AWS server runs on. It's probably as simple as running `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`

Comment: I'm sorry. My AWS server runs on Linux. So I can't use apt-get command itself.

Comment: What do you mean by _"So I can't use apt-get command itself"_? `apt-get` is ubuntu/debian (which are probably the most used Linux distros).

Comment: I'm sorry again. I should have said I am using CentOS earlier and am using "yum" instead of "apt-get". That is why i said that I can't use apt-get command.

Comment: Ah. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278561/how-to-install-php-mbstring-on-centos-6-2) might help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving a clue, but unfortunately I still have the error...

Answer (score 0):

You need the PHP exstion mbstring.

```
//if your using ubuntu or debian
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
//or if your using centos this should install it
yum install php
```

Comment: What distro are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the only problem is that you haven't enabled the mbstring extension in your linux machine. Since you already have php5.6 installed, what you need to do is run the following commands:

`sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring` -> Install the mbstring extension for php5.6
`systemctl restart apache2` or `sudo service apache2 restart` -> Restart the server to apply the changes

That should fix it.