# mbstring not found on centos 7

Tags: php, linux, centos7

I'm not able to install mbstring on Centos 7. I got error when running the command `yum install php-mbstring`.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.cogentco.com
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: mirror.ash.fastserv.com
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * updates: mirror.vtti.vt.edu
No package php-mbstring available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278561/how-to-install-php-mbstring-on-centos-6-2

Comment: none of the solutions worked for me