# phpMyAdmin for web

Tags: centos, yum, epel

I am trying to host phpmyadmin on my server.
I have centos 6.8 but when i load the phpmyadmin it shows 500 error.
I went to error log to check the error and I found this error:

> Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in
>   /var/www/html/phpMyAdminDlc/libraries/php-gettext/gettext.inc

So now I am trying to install mbstring using command

```
#yum install php-mbstring
```

But I get error

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
  Setting up Install Process
  Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
   * base: mirror.daniel-jost.net
   * epel: mirror.daniel-jost.net
   * extras: mirror.daniel-jost.net
   * updates: mirror.daniel-jost.net
   * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
  Resolving Dependencies
  --> Running transaction check
  ---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.3.3-48.el6_8 will be installed
  --> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-48.el6_8 for package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64
  --> Running transaction check
  ---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-48.el6_8 will be installed
  --> Processing Conflict: php55w-common-5.5.38-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5
  --> Finished Dependency Resolution
  Error: php55w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64
   You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
  ** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
  cronie-1.4.4-15.el6_7.1.x86_64 has missing requires of /usr/sbin/sendmail
  redhat-lsb-core-4.0-7.el6.centos.x86_64 has missing requires of /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

I cannot install php-mbstring.Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-mbstring
```

Afterthat restart the apache server

Refer:[How to install PHP mbstring on CentOS 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278561/how-to-install-php-mbstring-on-centos-6-2)

http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php